# Extract value from GCP logs, and display them using Stackdriver dashboard charts

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, dashboard, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

[Google Cloud Platform logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkMcP.png)

I want to extract the value of totalSessions from the logs above and display them in a line chart on Stackdriver dashboard.
It would be great if someone could give me an idea as to how I could create the log based metric and use it in Stackdriver.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics

Comment: Were you able to sort out how to plot this? I am looking at the exact same situation and can't find the relevant docs.